# CMake: How to setup unit testing of a library

Tags: c++, unit-testing, cmake, tdd, googletest

I work under a kata project to learn how to write unit tests in C++ ([link to the repository](https://github.com/rynkowsg/kata-DictionaryPath)). One of elements in that project is a DictionaryPath library. It's placed in a separate directory with dedicated `CMakeFile.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6 FATAL_ERROR)

add_library(DictionaryPath
        include/DictionaryPath/Dictionary.h
        src/Dictionary.cpp
        include/DictionaryPath/DictionaryPath.h
        src/DictionaryPath.cpp
        src/WordsGraph.cpp
        src/WordsGraph.h
        src/DijkstraAlgorithmImpl.cpp
        src/DijkstraAlgorithmImpl.h
        src/Path.cpp
        src/Path.h
        src/Graph.h
        src/ShortestPathAlgorithm.h
        src/DijkstraAlgorithm.h)

target_include_directories(DictionaryPath PUBLIC
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
    PRIVATE src)
```

It works find with other targets (clients of the library), but when I tried to add unit tests in the same subdirectory I encountered a problem how to define a target for unit test. E.q. `WordsGraph` class. I defined a target:

```
add_executable(WordsGraphTest test/WordsGraphTest.cpp)
target_link_libraries(WordsGraphTest GTest::main DictionaryPath)
add_test(NAME WordsGraphTest COMMAND WordsGraphTest)
```

But if I would try to refer to `WordsGraph` header file I have:

```
test/WordsGraphTest.cpp:9:10: fatal error: 'WordsGraph.h' file not found
```

I understand a reason - files in `src/` are private, but how in this case to test library internal files without implementation for every target that links to it? Should I duplicate compilation of necessary library files in each unit test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
add_library(DictionaryPath
        ...
        src/WordsGraph.h
        ...
)

target_include_directories(DictionaryPath PUBLIC
    ...
    PRIVATE src)
```

`WordsGraph.h` is in `src`, and you declared `src` as a private include directory for `DictionaryPath`.

If you don't want to do more than calling `target_link_libraries` when creating a unit test, you should either move `WordsGraph.h` into `include`, or declare `src` as a public or interface include directory.

If you don't want to move `WordsGraph.h` into `include`, nor declare `src` as a public or interface include directory, you should add a call to `target_include_directories`:

```
add_executable(WordsGraphTest test/WordsGraphTest.cpp)
target_link_libraries(WordsGraphTest GTest::main DictionaryPath)

target_include_directories(WordsGraphTest PRIVATE src)

add_test(NAME WordsGraphTest COMMAND WordsGraphTest)
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be easy to solve the problem you encountered (WordsGraph.h not found). You may use include_directories or target_include_directories.